# Help with determining a solution to $(1 - 2x^2) y'' - x y' + 6y = 0$ that satisfies $y(1)=-1$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following is an exercise problem in chapter 1 of Applied and Differential equations with BVP by Vladimir A. Dobrushkin.

Mostly what he did in chapter 1 is give examples of checking that something is a solution to a DE/IVP. In the exercise he asks that you:

> Determine a solution to the following differential equation: $$ (1 -
>  2x^2) y'' - x y' + 6y = 0 $$ of the form $y(x) = a + bx + cx^2$
> satisfying the normalization condition $y(1) = -1$.

How am I supposed to find the solution? Is this problem supposed to be solved using Mathematica or MATLAB because there's an emphasis on using them too which I just skipped for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By substitution you get $(1-2x^2)(2c) -x(2cx+b)+6(a+bx+cx^2)=0$

By equating coefficients and using your condition $a+b+c=-1$ you can determine a unique solution.

Note the coefficient of $x^2$ gives $-4c-2c+6c=0$

Comment: **you can determine a unique solution** how? You get 2 equations, in 3 unknowns $a,b,c$.

Comment: @Nasser Compare the coefficient of $x$ on the LHS (which is $5b$) with that on the other side (which is $0$). You get $b=0$. Now you have two equations and two unknowns. You will have $a=1/2$ and $c=-3/2$.

Comment: That is not what I get. When plugging in given $y$ into the ode, I get $6 a+2 c+5 b x=0$ and not $5 b x=0$  Why not then show the unique solution you obtained?

Comment: @Nasser $6a + 2c + 5bx=0x+0$. Compare coefficients for like terms to get $5b=0$ and $c + 3a=0$. The unique solution is $y(x)=(1-3x^2)/2$.